# JS dropdown navigation menu not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

This dropdown menu not showing any result while click.

JS code:

```
$('#king-mainmenu li a').on( 'click', function(e){
       if( !$(this.parentNode).find('ul').get(0) || $('body').width() > 1000 ){
            return true;
        }
       if( $(this.parentNode).hasClass('open') ){
            $(this.parentNode).removeClass('open');
            return true;
        }
       else $(this.parentNode).addClass('open');
       e.preventDefault();

       return false;
    });
```

Comment: Here is HTML part using JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/j0e5vmau/

Comment: The posted Code has some invalid character..

Comment: Also what is your expected behavior? In the fiddle you have not added any CSS

Comment: Buddy reddy,  its seems js have some issue, and expected behaviors- submenu should be work. but while click on home, nothing happening.

Comment: Can you update your fiddle with the CSS you have? because in the code you are using `open` class but o details on its definition

Comment: JSfiddle update please check now - https://jsfiddle.net/j0e5vmau/5/

Comment: Still no style rules for class `open`

Comment: I recommend rewriting this example so that the markup and CSS is as *minimal as possible*.  Making a dropdown menu should be easy.  If you strip your code down, you'll probably find your bug and if you don't you'll make it more inviting for others to investigate your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple demo:

```js
$("li#dropdown>a").click(function (){
  $(".dropdownMenu").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.nav li.mainMenu{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  float:left;
}
.nav li a{
  color:white;
  background-color:#48a8f8;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
li#dropdown a{
  position:relative;
}
ul.dropdownMenu{
  visibility:hidden;
  margin:6px 0 0 0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
}
ul.dropdownMenu.active{
  visibility:visible;
}
ul.dropdownMenu li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="mainMenu" id="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mainMenu"><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li class="mainMenu"><a href="">Projects</a></li>
  <li class="mainMenu"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```